# Sqlite database Android Cursor/Lock

Tags: android, database, sqlite, locking, cursor

I'm only reading my table but i cannot start the app because it gives me those errors:

Here's te code to connect to the dbclass. It calls the id method in the DBclass and then closes the db.

```
public int return_id_phone(Context contxt) {
    Database db = new Database(contxt);
    db.open();
    int id_phone = db.id(2);
    db.close();
    return id_phone;
}
```

and here's the code to extract. Only returns a number it's simple and I don't know why it is crashing. It says in the errors below that I don't close the cursor and also the db is lock.

Here's my database class. Yestarday was working perfect and today is not working...

> package com.background;

public class Database {

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "sync";

public static final String ID_ROW = "_ids";
public static final String VALUE_ROW = "_value";

public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String STATE = "state";

public static final String ID_CONTACTS = "idcontacts";
public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String NUMBER = "phone";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "faraway";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "sync";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_2 = "user";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_3 = "service";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_4 = "contacts";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String proba = "";

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_2 + " (" + ID_ROW
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + VALUE_ROW
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_3 + " (" + ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + STATE
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_4 + " (" + ID_CONTACTS
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NAME
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}

public Database(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;

}

public Database open() throws SQLException {

    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();

}

public long primerCop() {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, 1);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public long updateSync(int ids, int value) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, value);
    return ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=" + ids,
            null);

}

public long zeroAll(int ids) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, 0);
    return ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=" + ids,
            null);

}

public List<String> check() {

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "=1",
            null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null) {
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            list.add(c.getString(0));
        }

        return list;

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public long personaldata(Integer id) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(VALUE_ROW, id);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_2, null, cv);
}

public int id(int row) {
    String[] columns = new String[] { ID_ROW, VALUE_ROW };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_2, columns, ID_ROW + "='"
            + row+"'", null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        int id= c.getInt(1);
        c.close();
        return id;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public long prepare_service() {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(STATE, 0);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_3, null, cv);
}

public int chech_state(int id) {
    String[] columns = new String[] { ID, STATE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_3, columns, ID + "=" + id,
            null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        int a = c.getInt(1);
        c.close();
        return a;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}

public long update_s(int value, int id) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(STATE, value);
    return ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE_3, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id,
            null);
}

public boolean Preferences(int id) {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
            + id, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        int number = c.getInt(1);
        if (number == 1) {
            c.close();
            return true;
        } else {
            c.close();
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        c.close();
        return false;
    }
}

public long contact_table(String name, String number) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NAME, name);
    cv.put(NUMBER, number);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_4, null, cv);

}

public long update_name(String name, String number) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NAME, name);
    return ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE_4, cv, NUMBER + "='" + number
            + "'", null);
}

public long update_phone(String name, String number) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NUMBER, number);
    return ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE_4, cv, NAME + "='" + name
            + "'", null);
}

public JSONObject select_contact(String name, String number) {

    String queryf = "select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE_4 + " where " + NAME
            + "='" + name + "' or " + NUMBER + "='" + number + "'";
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(queryf, null);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
        // No hay usuario y lo insertamos en la db
        c.close();
        try {
            json.put("type", "upload");
            json.put("name", name);
            json.put("phone", number);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;

    } else {
        c.close();
        String queryf2 = "select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE_4 + " where "
                + NAME + "='" + name + "' and " + NUMBER + "='" + number
                + "'";
        Cursor c2 = ourDatabase.rawQuery(queryf2, null);

        if (c2.getCount() != 0) {
            c2.close();
            try {
                json.put("type", "exists");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return json;

        } else {

            c2.close();
            String queryf3 = "select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE_4
                    + " where " + NAME + "='" + name + "'";
            Cursor c3 = ourDatabase.rawQuery(queryf3, null);

            if (c3.getCount() != 0) {
                c3.close();
                try {
                    json.put("type", "change_phone");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return json;

            } else {
                String queryf4 = "select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE_4
                        + " where " + NUMBER + "='" + number + "'";
                Cursor c4 = ourDatabase.rawQuery(queryf4, null);

                if (c4.getCount() != 0) {
                    c4.close();
                    try {
                        json.put("type", "change_name");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return json;
                }
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

```
> 07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.anonyme.app/databases/faraway' 
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:2069)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1123)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1081)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1167)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:833)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at com.background.Database.open(Database.java:89)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at com.extract.Contacts.phoneandname(Contacts.java:124)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at com.anonyme.app.IntroActivity.uploadall(IntroActivity.java:85)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at com.anonyme.app.IntroActivity.onCreate(IntroActivity.java:76)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6938):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 11:54:05.460: E/System(6938): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
07-09 11:54:05.465: E/System(6938): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
07-09 11:54:05.465: E/System(6938):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2227)
07-09 11:54:05.465: E/System(6938):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2319)
07-09 11:54:05.465: E/System(6938):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2315)
07-09 11:54:05.465: E/System(6938):     at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
07-09 11:54:05.465: E/System(6938):     at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
07-09 11:54:05.465: E/System(6938):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2280)
07-09 11:54:05.465: E/System(6938):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1252)
07-09 11:54:05.465: E/System(6938):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:2040)
07-09 11:54:05.465: E/System(6938):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:182)
07-09 11:54:05.465: E/System(6938):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
07-09 11:54:05.465: E/System(6938):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Some code would be helpfull, how are you opening and especially closing the database?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in onCreate() your logs are ultimately pointing there only.
Please verify code where you are extending your class with:

```
extends SQLiteOpenHelper
```

If you are not able to solve please provide the code where you are creating your tables or the codes where your log is pointing on. Cause its just a blind guess otherwise.

Comment: ourDatabase.close() is missing. Since you never closed it that's the problem. Please verify and let me know.

Comment: Also, please delete your exact question "Android Sqlite extracting data not possible" before someone starts giving you negative voting

Comment: Yes I have read it already :) You need to put ourDatabase.close() in close() method of Database class.